# Angular 2 wrong path for system.import('app')

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, iis

I have a project asp.net-mvc with angular2 element. Use to start the iis application, that start index.cshtml in the Home folder (initiated from the home controller). So, I modified for angular, as follows, the index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="~/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="~/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="~/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, when i start the application `System.import('app')` don't find app folder because do this request:

> `zone.js`:1382 GET http://localhost/app/main.js 404 (Not Found)

however if I manually call the home controller, correctly displays the path:

> http://localhost/my_virtual_path/app/main.js

Why this behavior?
I can change the system.import so that see the path relative to the project level?

for completeness, this is the `system.config.js` :

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
        'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
        app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',

      // librerie di terze parti
      'angular2-datatable': 'npm:angular2-datatable',
      'lodash': 'npm:lodash/lodash.js',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },


      'angular2-datatable': {
          main: 'index.js',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

    }
  });
})(this);
```

Comment: Post the content of systemjs.config.js

Comment: I have added but I don't think that it is helpful since I do not want to change the relative paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I strongly suggest you don't use asp.net mvc or something like that for angular app. No need it. You can use it just as rest service (asp.net web api). Anyway, I think this problem comes from application path (IIS application)
So you need add this tag to html file head:

```
<head>
<base href="/my_virtual_path/">
.....
```

Comment: Resolve the problem but, i looking for a solution with relative path to avoid having to change the file when I share it with a coworker.

Comment: You can't do that like asp.net. Because asp.net renders pages at server. And notice that you don't need use (/my_virtual_path/) this because your path begins from root (www.domain.com). And don't forget base tag (<base href="/">)  is necessary in Angular2 apps (see reference). It's complete description for you.

Comment: And change your mind and forget asp.net approach. NO NEED server side rendering in angularjs, angular2 and ..... apps.